# Using JSzip to zip files by selecting through input

Tags: javascript, fileapi, jszip

I am trying to use JSZip to select some files(pdf/doc/txt) on my local system and zip them and then send them to server.

```
<input type="file" multiple />
```

I refered to [this](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/read-local-file-api.html) link which reads an existing zip file but I couldnt find an example where other files can be zipped.
My problem is very similar to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125109/need-to-zip-the-selected-file-from-client-machine-when-uploading-using-jszip-i)
When the files are selected from the input, the returned file object does not contain the path so there is no way to zip them since `JSZip.file` method needs the path of the file.